# How to set the slot color to an event Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, background, scheduler

I use the kendo Scheduler and need to know if you can change the color of the cells used in the event and not all cell scheduler.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzxNH.png)

Comment: someone help ? please!!!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean with 'change the color of the cells used in the event ' - could you please clarify?

Comment: Hello Vladimir Iliev,

What I am trying to do is change the bottom of the cell and not the event. Because there are days of the week that are disabled according to the setting made . 

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to color the slots of the Scheduler. This can be achieved as demonstrated in the following demo:

- [Set slot background color using slot templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/set-slot-background-color-using-slot-templates)

If you need to color the slots only when event is available above it than you should use the "dataBound" event of the Scheduler to get visible events (available from ["data" method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-data) of the Scheduler) start / end times, and iterate over the slots (you can get the cell slotObject by calling the ["slotByElement" method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-slotByElement)) to find which ones match event.

Comment: Hello Vladimir Iliev ,

Thank you for help, finally managed to resolve the error, but there is a new problem.
After deleting an event error " getTimezoneOffset of null " the return of my exclusion of service is equal to create and this does not show the error, which must return my service needs to make the event destroy without error ?

Thank you very much.